# Name of weird 70s movie with small hairy animal boy

Tags: story-identification, movie

There was this odd 70s movie with a small hairy animal boy. The movie had scientists and laboratories in it. I can’t remember any other details. Looked like a small wookiee.

Comment: Hi, this is a good start but do you have any more details at all? Were there other characters? Anything about the plot or setting? Modern day/future/prehistoric? Check you aren't assuming any details, and therefore missing them out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"The Ugly Little Boy" (1977 TV movie)?

This was a  movie based on the  short story by author Isaac Asimov. Below is a  clip from YouTube which maybe shows the scene that you're remembering.

Comment: If so, this has been asked and answered at least twice before here

Comment: @1.21 gigawatts. You can also watch the complete movie on YouTube, it's only about 26 minutes long.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds a bit like the TV series [*Land of the Lost*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land_of_the_Lost_(1974_TV_series)) from 1974. Cha-Ka was a small ape like boy they meet.

[image: Cha-Ka]

Answer (score 0):

Could this be Joan Crawford's last film, the 1970 *[Trog](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0066492/)*?

> Anthropologist Dr. Brockton (Joan Crawford) unearths a troglodyte (an Ice Age 'missing link" half-caveman, half-ape) and manages to domesticate him - until he's let loose by an irate land developer (Michael Gough) to go on a rampage and kidnap a little girl. Crawford's last feature film.

### Trailer

There's a longer plot summary [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PdhuAm35mhQ) which includes scenes in the lab.

Found with a Google search for `1970s film hairy boy`